# Trouble with JHipster's Improved Remember-Me Mechanism

Tags: jhipster, jhipster-gateway

I'm currently working with the latest version of JHipster and I intend to use it in a microservice environment. I want to use the authentication infrastructure jhipster provides and I've been trying to implement the improved Remember-Me mechanism as described in the official documentation.

I've added the remember-me tag in my application-dev.yml file, but I'm not seeing any updates related to the tokens in the database. I've double-checked my configuration, and everything seems to be in order.

Could anyone in the JHipster community shed some light on what might be causing this issue or provide any troubleshooting steps?

```yaml
  security:
    authentication:
      jwt:
        # This token must be encoded using Base64 and be at least 256 bits long (you can type `openssl rand -base64 64` on your command line to generate a 512 bits one)
        base64-secret: ZjBkZmE0NmMwZGU5YzYzMDE5MjRmNjk5N2I3ZTA2ZjI2NzZiNGZiOWMwYmVjYmZjNjJiNjFiZDkzNzJlNTI2ZDgwNTM3NTI0ZGE0Yjc2ZTBmMTBiYWIzZTE2ZDY4Yzk0MzhhOTA4YjMxMTRkNjk4OGExMzFmMzVkZDhhYzE2Njc=
        # Token is valid 24 hours
        token-validity-in-seconds: 86400
        token-validity-in-seconds-for-remember-me: 2592000
    remember-me:
      key: 0b32a651e6a65d5731e869dc136fb301b0a8c0e4
```

Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
Also, I have used the older version of jhipster and right now I am a bit confused about how tokens are being refreshed or even checked for validity. any insights regarding this process are also greatly appreciated.